# Wix - LGHT0094 Unresolved reference to symbol

Tags: wix

I'm trying to make an installer for Windows with WiX. I'm following [this](http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-2/) tutorial.

I get the following error:

```
trunk\Setup\Product.wxs(12): error LGH
T0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixUI:WixUI_InstallDir' in section 'Prod
uct:*'. [trunk\Setup.wixproj]
```

Here is my [Product.wxs](http://pastebin.com/i6BuTRRC) and my [setup.build](http://pastebin.com/eL0Qfm3E) file.
Thanks!

Comment: Please post all code here

Comment: That's all the relevant code.
If I delete the 12th line (`<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />`), the msbuild command runs fine.

Comment: @awesomeyi _'Please post all code here '_ Surely not! This should have stated ***Post the relevant code here!*** or asking for a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I'm doing now [@Nagy Vilmos](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2891426/nagy-vilmos)! (Note just providing links doesn't count here!)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're right. I'll be more specific next time.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix. That is a C++-tagged question. This is specific to WiX. The WiX compilation/linking model is analogous to C++ compiling and linking, but you won't find the answer to this question over there.